# Date time pciker doesn't works

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to add a date time picker to an input in a modal, but for some reason, I can't, when I make click in the input it doesn't display, I don't have an idea why but I need it for a better UX/UI in the modal, something that I try was change the id to the divs but it didn't work.
I'm leaving my code.

Modal

```html
<!-- Modal newevent-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade " id="newevent">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg mw-80 ">
        <div class="modal-content border-0 rounded">
          <div class="modal-body mr-4 ml-4 pr-2 pl-2">
            <form action="./plugins/login/php/completedetails" class="" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group ">
                <input maxlength="30" class="form-control-plaintext" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nueva Tarea" id="name" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><i class="fas fa-user mr-3 text-primary"></i>Responsable</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><i class="fas fa-stream mr-3 text-primary"></i>Estado</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><i class="fas fa-calendar-day mr-3 text-primary"></i>Fecha de entrega</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 input-group">
                  <input type="text" id="datetimepicker-default" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><i class="fas fa-stopwatch mr-3 text-primary"></i>Tiempo estimado</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3 col-sm-8">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">h</span>
                  </div>
                </div>


              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="inputPassword4">Descripción</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Añade detalles"></textarea>
          </div>


        </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Scripts and stylesheets

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
/>
<!-- ELemeentos añadidos para el datepicker -->
<!-- jquery JS -->
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap js -->
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
></script>

<!-- Propeller textfield js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/propeller.min.js"></script>

<!-- Datepicker moment with locales -->
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  language="javascript"
  src="datetimepicker/js/moment-with-locales.js"
></script>

<!-- Propeller Bootstrap datetimepicker -->
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  language="javascript"
  src="datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"
></script>

<script>
  // Default date and time picker
  $("#datetimepicker-default").datetimepicker();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  datetimepicker init success before html render
check state html create after script
try $(document).ready(function(){$("#datetimepicker-default").datetimepicker();
});